# Problems with my program or netbeans error

Tags: java, netbeans

I was doing an exercise and in which you ask us the following: Exercise 06: Read the data corresponding to two tables of 12 numerical elements and mix them in a third of the form: 3 from tables A, 3 from B, others 3 of the A, another 3 of the B, Etc. When making the code (according to me it is fine) I get an error in netbeans (attached a photo) can you tell me what is the reason for my error? I'm still a student. In advance thank you very much for reading (I attach my code and the image of the error).

```
package ejercicioarreglos_06;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class EjercicioArreglos_06 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     
        int tablaA[] = new int[12];
        int tablaB[] = new int[12];
        int contador = 0;
        boolean eleccion = true;
        int contA = 0, contB = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < tablaA.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Ingresa el valor " + (i + 1) + " de la tabla A: ");
            tablaA[i] = in.nextInt();

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < tablaB.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el valor " + (j + 1) + " de la tabla B: ");
            tablaB[j] = in.nextInt();

        }

        for (int k = 0; k < tablaB.length + tablaB.length; k++) {
            if (eleccion = true) {

                System.out.println(tablaA[contA]);
                contador++;
                contA++;
                if (contador > 2) {
                    eleccion = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print(tablaB[contB]);
                contador--;
                contB++;
                if (contador < 0) {
                    eleccion = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: There are StackOverflow pages for different languages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/
Please try to translate this into English (even google translate). The community hear largely speaks English, even though it is international

Comment: sorry i'm new to this community right now i am modifying my question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's not in English language

Comment: I need to know something concerning your post. Then I will help you fixing the most prominent problem.

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: it means you are trying to get the 13th element of an array that has maximum 12 elements

Comment: No, I want to show 3 elements from each table until they finish showing the 24 elements (12 from table A and 12 from Table B), my program does allow me to enter the data but it doesn't show me anything. there is an image attached.

Comment: Replace your if statement if (eleccion = true) with if (eleccion) and I think it should fix your issue

Comment: ok i will try to have what happens

Comment: I would really like to know how it happened that you posted in a different language than English. I have a theory that this happens when users have an auto-translating browser and hence get the false impression that all of StackOverflow is in their language. I would therefor appreciate if you could describe how it was for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

It is an exception (error) that happens when we provide an index outside the limits allowed for the access of elements in an array. Remember that Java indexes start at 0 and go up to the number of elements -1.

Note the position of the public class ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the class hierarchy of the Java platform:

-> java.lang.Object

--> java.lang.Throwable

---> java.lang.Exception

----> java.lang.RuntimeException

-----> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

------> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Here is an example where we try to access an element of an array using an invalid index:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    // an array of five elements
    int[] values = {8, 98, 100, 3, 14};     

    // we will provide an invalid index
    System.out.println(values[5]); 

    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

This code compiles normally. However, when we try to run it, we get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
  at Study.main(Test.java:7)
```

The most appropriate way to correct this error is to provide an index value that is really in the allowed range.

Answer (score 0):

The **If condition** available seems to be true always and I corrected it to make the code work i.e.,  from **if (eleccion = true)** to **if (eleccion)**

```
package ejercicioarreglos_06;


import java.util.Scanner;

public class EjercicioArreglos_06 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     
        int tablaA[] = new int[12];
        int tablaB[] = new int[12];
        int contador = 0;
        boolean eleccion = true;
        int contA = 0, contB = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < tablaA.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Ingresa el valor " + (i + 1) + " de la tabla A: ");
            tablaA[i] = in.nextInt();

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < tablaB.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el valor " + (j + 1) + " de la tabla B: ");
            tablaB[j] = in.nextInt();

        }

        for (int k = 0; k < tablaB.length + tablaB.length; k++) {
            if (eleccion) {

                System.out.println(tablaA[contA]);
                contador++;
                contA++;
                if (contador > 2) {
                    eleccion = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.print(tablaB[contB]);
                contador--;
                contB++;
                if (contador < 0) {
                    eleccion = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```